# one component Gaussian fit with python is not working

Tags: python, arrays, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

i have the orange peak that I want to do a Gaussian fit on with the aim of obtaining an estimate of the FWHM and the maximum temperature:
[image]

The function is given by:

```
def Gauss(velo_peak, a, mu0, sigma):
          res = a * np.exp(-(velo_peak - mu0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
          return res
```

And my code is:

```
i1,i2 = 0,len(y)
n = len(x[i1:i2])
mu0 = sum(x[i1:i2] * y[i1:i2])/n
sigma = sum(y[i1:i2]*(x[i1:i2] - mu0)**2)/n
peak = max(y)
p0 = [peak, mu0, sigma]   # a = max(spec_peak)
popt,pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, x, y, p0, maxfev=100000)
```

but the fit is not working, I have tried playing around with the guess values but I cant find any reason why it is not working. any help would be much apreciated.
The x-axis is given by this data:

```
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.774
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.775
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.776
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.777
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.778
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.779
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.78
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.781
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.782
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.783
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.784
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.785
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.786
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.787
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.788
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.789
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.79
109.791
109.791
```

and the y axis:

```
-0.0693423
-0.0383312
-0.0130822
0.00771434
-0.00475569
-0.0288578
-0.00323742
0.000307108
-0.0181949
0.00129764
0.00661946
-0.0116734
0.0439911
-0.0189704
0.0134336
0.017783
-0.00059444
0.00129813
-0.0146921
-0.0178051
0.00210355
0.00739107
0.0193562
0.0177199
-0.0115096
-0.0148834
-0.0359211
0.0268527
0.0159948
0.0214348
0.015795
0.00807647
-0.0597478
-0.037623
0.000166686
0.0119881
0.0127355
0.00687692
0.00479245
-0.0207917
0.0627117
0.0133312
0.011981
0.0308865
0.0323675
-0.0353238
0.0498601
0.00484114
-0.00354253
-0.0181545
0.0476038
0.019046
0.0195323
-0.013426
-0.0154619
0.0129866
-0.0158984
0.0126304
0.0269754
-0.00217857
0.0206669
-0.0219605
-0.0224113
0.00217749
-0.0359304
0.0273953
0.0133183
0.0202708
-0.0144499
0.0351752
-0.0202478
-0.0074738
0.0127188
-0.0116596
0.00869577
-0.0234507
0.0373167
0.00263353
0.0166561
-0.0043449
-0.0229105
-0.00741182
0.0467549
-0.0235804
-0.0191783
0.0528504
-0.00901956
0.043926
0.0223436
0.0181945
-0.0400392
0.0220731
-0.0167595
0.0214929
0.028309
-0.0234769
-0.0419024
0.0131882
-0.00421679
0.00359541
-0.055839
-0.0599337
-0.0283572
0.00686772
-0.00965801
0.0164275
0.00458221
-0.00909531
0.138937
0.297971
0.247663
0.124508
0.0365572
-0.00971529
0.0238192
-0.0509615
-0.0101447
-0.0298155
-0.0196555
0.0224242
-0.0329058
-0.00786179
-0.00347346
-0.0102662
0.0111553
0.013002
-0.0375893
0.00996665
-0.0125302
-0.00829957
0.0366645
0.0219919
-0.038467
-0.0260219
-0.0375669
0.00625599
-0.0498297
0.0258702
-0.0217369
-0.0349204
-0.014657
-0.0180611
-0.0420286
-0.000379184
-0.0333805
-0.0551173
-0.0224908
0.0179898
0.020866
0.0288823
-0.0182207
-0.0413725
-0.0162658
0.00223817
0.0243006
-0.0170214
0.0320711
0.0012465
0.00344509
0.00150138
-0.00169928
-0.0139581
0.0552647
0.0229482
-0.00316584
-0.033333
0.000161762
-0.00905961
-0.00685663
-0.0162735
-0.0399026
0.0270222
0.00798811
-0.00408101
-0.0072991
0.0112089
-0.012056
0.0146916
-0.00340297
0.0217221
0.00722562
-0.0203967
-0.0150112
0.00900151
0.0322559
0.00482019
-0.000814166
-0.0225995
-0.00817639
0.0201735
-0.0285309
0.0355886
0.000298672
-0.0129141
0.0428829
-0.028223
0.0183822
-6.62023e-05
0.0358768
-0.0293772
0.0125377
-0.00919312
0.00703798
0.00537255
-0.00413266
0.0505678
-0.00586183
0.0087835
-0.0113064
-0.0198051
0.0477742
0.00607189
-0.0112695
0.0288124
0.0354801
-0.0550288
-0.00167514
-0.0440247
-0.00573284
0.0138037
0.0170393
-0.0350715
0.0333013
```

Comment: can you cross check the provided x data.

Comment: i re-changed the data, maybe it is better

Comment: You are rounding too many digits, one needs at least one more, probably 2 ( you have 109.777 thirteen times similar for the other values)

Comment: is there a way i can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical reason for the fail is: wrong starting parameters. The formulae used here are somewhat those that would be used for a measurement statistic, while the data here has to be considered the according histogram. The use of `n`, hence, does not make sense. It is more like

```py
## smoothing the data with its own noisy Gaussian
ysmooth = np.convolve( y, y[::-1], mode="same")
mu0 = sum( x * y ) / sum( y )
## the abs() is wrong but the strong noise forces it
sigma = np.sqrt( sum( np.abs( ysmooth ) * (  ( x - mu0 ) )**2 ) / sum( np.abs(ysmooth)) )
peak = max( y )
```

The total scale `n` is unknown but the relative amount of `x` values is gives as the value of the histogram, i.e. `y`.
The guess for `sigma` is a bit messy, but works here. It is quite of but the fit converges without increasing `maxfev`